# Regex matches end of line twice

Tags: java, regex

I am using text files to hold all of the written text for my game. I am trying to get the description of an item by splitting the text of a text file into names and descriptions, by line, using `allText.split(regex)`. The text file looks like this:

```
Claws:Sharp claws capable of inflicting damage.
Potion:A drink that heals wounds.
```

and the regex looks like this:

```
[:\n\r]
```

The regex correctly matches the colons, but it does something weird for the newlines. Instead of matching once, at the end of the first line, it matches twice, at that point...

To see where those splits are made look here: http://fiddle.re/gn8ew6 (the first line is 47 characters and the second line is 33).

How do I prevent this from happening?

Comment: It matches twice because the end of the line is either `\n\r` or `\r\n`. One fix would be to read line by line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is matching twice at the ends of the lines because your lines end with either a `\n\r` or a `\r\n`. You could [use a regex like this](http://ideone.com/q0SBjn):

```
:|\n\r?+|\r\n?+
```

Basically, this matches a `:`, or it matches `\n` followed by an optional `\r` (consuming the `\r` if it was there), or it matches `\r` followed by an optional `\n` (again consuming the `\n` if it was there)

However, I would recommend you simply read the file line-by-line. You can do that with a `BufferedReader`:

```
BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new File(filename)));
read.readLine(); //reads a line
```

Comment: Thanks :) Your regex works! The reason I'm not reading line by line is because LibGdx, the library that I use, has a method for the files it reads that returns all of the text within the file, so I may as well use that method before I write my own input code.

Answer (score 0):

I encourage you, in use another away,try it:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("regex");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("your text");

while(matcher.find()) {
  System.out.println("found: " + matcher.group(1));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this Regex on RegexPlanet with the MULTILINE option enabled: `:(.*)?$`

Read about MULTILINE Patterns in Java on Google to understand how you can use them. I tested this on the link you provided and it works, it gets it in group(1) for both lines.

Using the start and end methods you can also get the location for each group ([6,47] and [56,82] in your example).

Answer (score 0):

You can change your regex to match the names and descriptions as separate groups, with your regex either matching an EOL or newline character as follows:-

```
(.*?):(.*?)(\n|$)
```